# React/redux + bootstrap, make modal show unique for component

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, redux

I have a component that shows a modal to pop up some content in my map. I have a pretty straight forward set up :

The JSX looks like this :

```
  <Modal show={this.props.results.showPreviewModal} >
         {myPreviewContent}
  </Modal>
```

2 action-creators to open, close, and set the current item :

```
export function previewAsset(result) {
    return {
        currentResult: result,
        type: actions.PREVIEW_ASSET
    };
}

export function closePreviewModal() {
    return {
         type: actions.CLOSE_PREVIEW_MODAL
    };
}
```

And their reducers :

```
case actions.PREVIEW_ASSET:
      return state.set('currentPreview', action.currentResult).set('showPreviewModal', true);

case actions.CLOSE_PREVIEW_MODAL:
      return state.set('showPreviewModal', false);
```

Now, this seems to work fine. However, the issue is that the component that has the modal inside of it is inside a map, as it is a singular search result (each result component has a some functionality so it is it's own component that is mapped over with results). The issue is that if I have 10 results, this modal opens 10 times when I click the button that fires the `previewAsset` action.

This makes sense, because the `showPreviewModal` is accessible by all components, but what I am wondering is if there is a way to make then unique for each component individually, so only the 1 modal opens, not all 10.  Unsure how to approach this within react/redux, would very much appreciate any advice, thanks!

Comment: Do you have 10 instances of the `<Model />`?

Comment: By the way, redux reducers must not modify the existing state. They should return a new state always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach I've used successfully is to pull the Modal component out of the loop (or `map()` in this case), and have a reducer for `currentItem` or something similar, which gets set when an item is selected (you could also use `currentItemIndex`, and then select the current item based on that in your `connect()` call).

In the parent component, you'd have the Modal as a child, and only display it if that `currentItem` is not null.

Here's a quick JSBin example to show you what I mean:

http://jsbin.com/fefoxoy/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: This is exactly what i ended up doing, so I will mark this correct. Thanks!

Comment: I would like to say that although I use the phrase "quick" JSBin, it probably took a good 30 min to whip that up lol